# Nested Array Iteration for array of objects find all values search filter

Tags: javascript, typescript

**Issue Unable to return testcaseid from array to this.filteredArray**

*able to return header value and all values of array if search word is empty.*

help me on this.

help how to iterate testcaseid and header on search input filed.

*Array -*

```
 PanelList$: any[] =
[
   {
      "header":"header1",
      "data":[
         {
            "testcaseId":"tz_param",
            "description":"tz_param"
         },
         {
            "testcaseId":"tzication",
            "description":"tzication"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "header":"security",
      "data":[
         {
            "testcaseId":"tz_prompt",
            "description":"tz_prompt"
         },
         {
            "testcaseId":"z_Root_CA",
            "description":"z_Root_CA"
         },
         {
            "testcaseId":"tz_part1",
            "description":"tz_part1"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

*input search code -*

```
 <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value);" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search Test Cases...">
```

*Filter Function -* to search header and testcase id

```
applyFilter(filterWord) {

let arraycase;
let arraycase1;

const word = filterWord.toString().toLowerCase();

this.filteredArray = this.PanelList$.filter(his => {

    if(his.header.toString().toLowerCase() ===  word) {
      console.log('1' + 'header')
      return his}


    if(his.header.toString().toLowerCase().includes(word)) {
      console.log('2' + 'return full array')
      return his}

   his.data.filter(ids => { 

      if(ids.testcaseId.toString().toLowerCase() ===  word) {
        console.log('3')

        arraycase = [{header: his.header, data: [ids] }]
        console.log(arraycase);
        return  arraycase
      } {

      return  arraycase
      }
      
    })

    console.log(arraycase1 + 'asdads');
  
})
```

**Update 1** -

```
      this.PanelList$ = JSON.parse(msg.data);
      this.filteredArray = JSON.parse(msg.data);
```

both this.PanelList$ and this.filteredArray  has same array

Comment: please add the wanted result for an empty word.

Comment: for empty word it will return entire array as mentioned in this.PanelList$

Answer (score 1):

Final Answer to my question - i am returning the value as i am expected -

```
applyFilter(filterWord) {
    console.log(this.PanelList$);
    let arraycase;
    const word = filterWord.toString().toLowerCase();

    this.filteredArray = this.PanelList$.map((his) => {
      if (his.header.toString().toLowerCase() === word) {
        return his;
      }

      if (his.header.toString().toLowerCase().includes(word)) {
        return his;
      }

      arraycase = [];

      his.data.filter((ids) => {
        if (ids.testcaseId.toString().toLowerCase() === word) {
          arraycase = { header: his.header, data: [ids] };
          console.log(arraycase);
          return arraycase;
        }
      });
      return arraycase;
    });


    if (this.filteredArray[0].length === 0) {
      this.testCaseIdTable = true;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not have all of your code I just added some required modifications so that I can test and you can have an idea how to modify your code.

```js
  //applyFilter(filterWord) {

let arraycase;
let arraycase1;

PanelList =
[
   {
      "header":"TestBootNotification_CS",
      "data":[
         {
            "testcaseId":"tc_real_module_param",
            "description":"tc_real_module_param"
         },
         {
            "testcaseId":"tc_BootNotification",
            "description":"tc_BootNotification"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "header":"security",
      "data":[
         {
            "testcaseId":"tc_with_prompt",
            "description":"tc_with_prompt"
         },
         {
            "testcaseId":"tc_install_Root_CA",
            "description":"tc_install_Root_CA"
         },
         {
            "testcaseId":"tc_install_client_cert_part1",
            "description":"tc_install_client_cert_part1"
         }
      ]
   }
]

   
  var word =  "TestBootNotification_CS".toString().toLowerCase();  //filterWord.toString().toLowerCase();

this.filteredArray = 
PanelList.map( 
    (his) => {

        if(his.header.toString().toLowerCase() ===  word) {
          console.log('1' + 'header')
          return his}
    
    
        if(his.header.toString().toLowerCase().includes(word)) {
          console.log('2' + 'return full array')
          return his}
    
          arraycase = [] 
          his.data.filter(ids => { 
    

          if(ids.testcaseId.toString().toLowerCase() ===  word) {
            console.log('3')
    
            // arraycase = [{header: his.header, data: [ids] }]
            var obj = {header: his.header, data: [ids] }
            arraycase.push( obj )
            console.log(arraycase);
            return  arraycase
          } else {
    
          return  arraycase
          }
          
        })
    
        console.log(arraycase1 + 'asdads') 
    }
 

 )



console.log( this.filteredArray  )
```

Comment: after using your code getting error - 

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'header' of undefined